# Dynamic form fields implemented as a map in a spring MVC form

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My problem is quite strightforward: I'm using Spring-MVC 4, and I really would like to implement dynamic form fields using a map.
In other words, my user should be able to dynamically populate a map included in the model.

It's the dear old input field followed by a "add" sign. If you hit the sign, a new empty field will appear.

The point is that in my case the fields are two, being the first the key and the second the value of the map.

I know that a common solution for list exists.
If my model has a `private List list` attribute, I can use a little javascript to generate

```
<input name="list[someIndex].someProperty" value="someValue" />
```

in order to instruct the framework to add a new item to the list, but I don't know how to preceed with maps.

Answer (score 0):

Try **@MatrixVariable** like this.

```
// GET /owners/42;q=11;r=12/pets/21;q=22;s=23

@RequestMapping(path = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void findPet(
        @MatrixVariable Map<String, String> matrixVars,
        @MatrixVariable(pathVar="petId"") Map<String, String> petMatrixVars) {

    // matrixVars: ["q" : [11,22], "r" : 12, "s" : 23]
    // petMatrixVars: ["q" : 11, "s" : 23]

}
```

You can see more here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I don't feel that this solution fits the problem. Matrix variables can be definitely used to pass parameters in URLs but it is not the spring way for forms. My information is supposed to be passed in a model (the Model, indeed) and Spring-MVC manages all these aspects. If I opt for marix variables I'll leave the paradigm looking for a different strategy.